# How can I add TextBoxes to an existing Matrix in an SSRS project?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids, rdl

Why is it that a control that appears in the property list in a BIDS project is not represented in the corresponding .rdl file?

Let me step back a bit; I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to add items to an existing report, either via the XML (.rdl viewed as code) or on the design surface. I can click on a rectangle on the design surface and see a column row above it:

[image]

And if I click on the "pipe"-separated segements on that column heading row, I see "MatrixColumn4", "MatrixColumn3", "MatrixColumn2", and "MatrixColumn1" in the designer; for example, here's MatrixColumn3:

[image]

However, only one of these columns appears at a time in the Property list - if I select MatrixColumn3 on the design surface, MatrixColumn1, MatrixColumn2, and MatrixColumn4 are not there. The same holds true for selecting any of the others - it turns up temporarily in the Properties list but "hides" all the others:

[image]

Stranger yet, when I search the .rdl file (viewed as XML) for "MatrixColumn1" (or "2" or "3" or "4") they do not exist there. In fact, the only reference to "MatrixColumn" in the entire file is this:

```
<Matrix Name="matrix1">
      <MatrixColumns>
        <MatrixColumn>
          <Width>1.67609in</Width>
        </MatrixColumn>
      </MatrixColumns>
  . . .
```

This seems exceedingly bizarre - shouldn't there be four sets of `<MatrixColumn></MatrixColumn>` there?

I want to add another column heading, with a Textbox-as-label and a Textbox below that to display dynamic content, but how can I do it without adding another column heading?, or at least making room for this new column?

I can increase the width of the matrix ("matrix1") by dragging it or by increasing its Size.Width value, but its existing contents expand with it, giving me no room to add TextBoxes inside of it.

Maybe I'm approaching SSRS from a completely wrong mental angle, as I don't see much of a connection between what the report generates and what I see on the design surface and in the XML.

Comment: I would strongly advise not playing with the xml if you can help it.  It's not clear to me from your question what you desired output is?  Do you want to display 2 columns of data under a single column header?  Do you just want to add another column to the matrix/tablix?  Please advise and we can try to help further

Comment: @Jonnus: The XML seems easier to work with than the design surface; the XML is confusing, but the design surface is that plus very frustrating. What I want to do is add another column (a label on the column header and a textbox with repeating data values below that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add another column to a matrix right click the column header and Select Insert column.  Then choose either inside group (left or right), or outside group (left or right).

- A column created inside the group will repeat for every item in the column group
- A column created outside the group will only appear the once to the left or right of the grouped columns.

Are you sure you are referring to a matrix (dynamic columns and rows) and not a tablix (dynamic number of rows only)?

The process for tablixes is the same as for matrixes as described above, just without the inside/outside group option.

Either method described above will include a new column with a single text box to label the column with, and another text box underneath to put the detail in.

You can also do this process by dragging a field from your dataset in the Report Data panel to the appropriate location in your existing table.

Please let me know if this helps, or if I've misunderstood your question and you require a different solution.

Comment: When I right-click the column header ("MatrixColumnN"), the context menu items are "Add Column Group", "Add Row Group" and "Properties" only - there is no "Insert column"...

Comment: What development environment are you using (the image looks like BIDS for VS2008)

Comment: "Are you sure you are referring to a matrix (dynamic columns and rows) and not a tablix (dynamic number of rows only)?" No, I'm not sure at all. This is all completely new to me. I'm taking a "break" from Web API / Excel Interop work, which I miss terribly at the moment.

Comment: This is VS2005. I also have it in VS2008 (as of this morning, but cannot see the design surface - 2-clicking the .rdl file only opens the XML view, not the "form" view in VS2008...

Comment: "You can also do this process by dragging a field from your dataset in the Report Data panel to the appropriate location in your existing table." The column I need to add is a computed column - it's not one of the fields of the dataset, but a value calculated by performing some math on a couple of those values.

Comment: Ah, I don't have VS 2005 installed, and I know that SSRS took a huge leap forward between 2005 and 2008.  Have you seen this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155996(v=sql.90).aspx ?  It looks to me like you are using a tablix as none of the columns have a large bracket (like /------------\\) in it.  Also, if dragging a column is an option at all you can drag any field onto the table, and then just delete the auto-generated header and data fields in it

Comment: Thanks for the link; I'll czech it out. I don't have a field to drag, though...I just have what I think will be the correct formula/expression so far.

Comment: The link talks about a table, which I don't have; I guess because the report uses a Stored Procedure rather than a table. The VS2005 project does have a "Datasets" view, but I don't see how to show that in VS2008.